# Karate scenario for array object in Rest JSON output

Tags: karate

I have an output of get operation like :

[
    {
        "field1": "123",
        "field2": [
            "10008"
        ],
        "field3": "ABC",
        "field4": [
            "XYZ"
        ],
    }]

Now I want to match the filed 4 output in the feature file. I have tried options like:

When method GET
Then status 200
And match $response.field4[*] contains ['XYZ']

but I am not getting the desired results and getting Karateexception. Can anyone guide what i am doing wrong and how to match the output of array fields.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your JSON structure carefully please:

```
* def response = [ { "field1": "123", "field2": [ "10008" ], "field3": "ABC", "field4": [ "XYZ" ] } ]
* match response[0].field4 contains 'XYZ'
```